# Date in X-Axis - .Net Charts

Tags: c#-4.0, mschart

i am working in .Net Charts. i want to show date in X-Axis. For ex : if i select Last 52 Weeks, then i should show the chart for last 52 weeks, whereas those 52 weeks start date should be in x-axis.  I am not having any idea, how to do this..I had tried with the code..

```
        DateTime Frm = sessionManager.ChartViewPeriodFrom;
        DateTime To = sessionManager.ChartViewPeriodTo;

        double min = Frm.ToOADate();
        double max = To.ToOADate();

        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Minimum = min;
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Maximum = max;
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = 7;
```

Here i am getting the Frm as "9/17/2011 12:00:00 AM" But, in the chart the minimum date starts from "9/21/2011 12:00:00 AM". How to fix this...

I had tried like this also..[ Edited Part ]

```
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueType = ChartValueType.Date;
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Minimum = (new DateTime(2011, 09, 17, 12, 00, 00)).ToOADate();
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Maximum = (new DateTime(2012, 09, 08, 12, 00, 00)).ToOADate();
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = 7;
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.IsMarginVisible = false;
```

Comment: Still i dint find any solutions..

Comment: once again I can't reproduce your problem, as your code produces the expected result on my setup.

Comment: Any other solutions..still i am getting same problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long search...i had fixed my above issue...but still i dont know how it works...

```
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.IntervalAutoMode = IntervalAutoMode.VariableCount;
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueType = ChartValueType.Date;
        DayOfWeek ds = DayOfWeek.Wednesday;
        double dblIntervalOffset = Convert.ToDouble(ds);
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.IntervalOffset = dblIntervalOffset;
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Minimum = min;
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Maximum = max;
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = 7;
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.IsMarginVisible = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

`Indexed` attribute must be set for series data.