# X -Axis First Value not shown - MS Charts

Tags: c#-4.0, mschart

I am working in .Net Charts. i am showing the column chart for last 52 weeks. so that it will starts from "17/09/2011 to 08/09/2012".

```
            Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Minimum = min;
            Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Maximum = max;
            Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = 7;
            Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.IsMarginVisible = true;
```

I had used the above code. But i am getting only 51 columns. I cant able to view the First Column (i.e) 17/09/2011 record.

[image]

In the image, see the first column is blank. But i am having value for that..

Comment: Explicitly, what is your `min` value, and what happens if you subtract a small epsilon from your `min` value, like `min - 1.0e-6`?

Comment: all date values...Minimum will be 17/09/2011 and the maximum will be  08/09/2012...I am getting the last 52 weeks records..

Comment: But shouldn't `Axis.Minimum` and `.Maximum` be `double`s? See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axis.minimum). I am not sure about date(time)-to-double conversion, but maybe it is worthwhile to verify that floating point rounding is not playing a trick on you.

Comment: I took a look at your previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12382247/650012), where the minimum `DateTime` is set to _12.00. Sep 17, 2011_. What if you set the time-of-day to _00.00_ instead?